# Nginx proxying not working, returning 400 error

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

So I have my sites available file set up as follows:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location /legacy/ {
    proxy_pass https://my.domain.com/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host https://my.domain.com/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }
```

However, whenever I go to my.domain.com/leagcy/ I get a 400 error directly back and no redirection or proxying taking place. Any ideas as to what I have done wrong?

Comment: Try removing `proxy_set_header Host https://my.domain.com/;`

Comment: that seems to have worked partially, it now seems to reverse proxy kinda, but all relative links are 404ing

Comment: and when I try and hit an API endpoint I still get a 400

Answer (score 0):

You probably use regular expressions in `server_name` and you're sending requests without setting `Host` header to any value.

> `$host` variable contains in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the 'Host' request header field, or the server name matching a request

Which causes invalid `Host` header to be send to upstream.